# Methods for comparing degree of structural coupling between two time series

Tags: time-series, python, cross-correlation, neuroscience, audio

I have two arrays, one representing an auditory stimulus and the other representing neural activity from auditory cortex. The auditory stimulus has known temporal and spectral structure. The neural data has unknown structure, but visual inspection suggests that some stimulus types elicit neural responses with temporal structure similar to that of the stimulus. I'm wondering how best to compare stimulus structure to the response structure in a way that allows me to quantify the degree of structural coupling, thus which stimulus type causes the strongest coupling. I'm assuming that a cross-correlation method could be appropriate, but I'm not sure if it's the best method, or if there are good alternatives.

Comment: A joint vector embedding space with learned neural networks is a possibility. But one needs a careful methodology to avoid spurious results (the networks can map anything to anything, including meaningless mappings)